# How to prevent rsync compression on files with no extension?

Tags: shell, compression, rsync

I'm using rsync to perform synchronisation between two machines on a network, so I have rsync's --compress setting enabled, however I have various file-types that I'm excluded that I know are already compressed such .jpg, .mp4 etc, using the --skip-compress option.

However, I have a large number of files with no extension that I know to have poor compression (due to encryption), as part of OS X's sparsebundle disk image format (where each "block" of the image is its own file with no file extension.

Anyway, I don't have many other files that should conflict, as other files that I have with no extension should be either excluded already or are quite small (so not really worth compressing).

However, I'm at a loss as to how I should add no extension files to rsync's --skip-compress list?

Answer (score 0):

Going up one level: How much time are you saving with `--skip-compress`?

On a 0.5 megabyte/s network link, a 21 megabyte mp3 file with suffices `mp3`, `txt` and none I tried
`--skip-compress="[]/gz/foo"` and `--skip-compress="gz//foo"`. I could not find a difference in the speed over 5 tries.

Comment: The device I'm targeting is a NAS with a fairly modest ARM processor so compression does add a lot of overhead, especially for files that aren't actually compressing well as it just adds unnecessary processing. Skipping compression on .mp4 files in particular saves a lot of time as such files are already as compressed as they can get.

Comment: Does `--skip-compress="[]"` or `--skip-compress="gz//mp4"` improve the speed?